# Accessing name of Publish Profile in wpp.targets

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, webdeploy

I have a web application that I publish using VS 2010 and Web Deploy. Because I need to publish the application to different sites, I have created different publishing profiles which, for example, I've named SITE1 and SITE2.

To customize behavior, I added a .wpp.targets file and, in that file, I'm able to reference things like $(Configuration), but I have not been able to figure out if it's possible to reference the name of the publishing profile (SITE1 or SITE2).

Is there a variable for the publishing profile name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $(PublishProfileName) variable to get the name of the current publish profile, at least in VS 2012.